# Spring boot with gradle and log4j2 not logs to file

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, log4j2

I have start working with spring boot and gradle and I am trying to use log4j2 for logging.
I am first compiling and building:

```
gradlew clean build
```

and after than execute jar:

```
java -jar build/libs/java-apns-notifier-0.1.0.jar
```

After executing jar I can see log in the console but not in the file mentioned in log4j2.xml(D:/temp/logs/apns.log). In that file I can see only logs from springframework but not from my code.
Question is how to make this simple scenario to work?
I want to see that my logs also appears in the log file.

Here is the source code: [Java Apple Push Notification Service Notifier](https://github.com/gandra/java-apns-notifier)

IMPORTANT!
I have recently noticed that logs appears. But only after I kill the process.
So to clarify here is what is going on:

1. Run jar with:

> java -jar build/libs/java-apns-notifier-0.1.0.jar

-> Nothing appears in the log file

2. Kill process in the comand line.
   -> Log appears in the log file

Comment: Have you checked that your log4j config is added to the JAR correctly? For example have you unzipped the JAR and made sure everything is where it should be?

Comment: Yes.
http://i.imgur.com/fHv4PpH.png  
http://i.imgur.com/24ECSY0.png  
Config is taken regarding to the fact that log4j2 writes to log file D:/temp/logs/apns.log  
Problem is that oinly springframework logs are writen and none from my app.

Comment: Does your configuration work correctly when not packaged inside a JAR? Like when you start the application in your IDE?

Comment: The same when starting from ide. No entry in the log file from my code.

Comment: More than likely, log4j2 isn't finding your config file since it is in the resources package and not at the root of the classpath. try passing in the jvm parameter '-Dlog4j.configurationFile="path to file" ' if that works you just need to either set the property or move your config file.

Comment: I'd also try setting append to true on your log file to make sure logs are not getting overwritten.

Comment: @alan7678,
log4j2 takes into account logging level specified in file. So it finds file and takes debug info. Did you try to execute code in you local env?

Comment: Firewall restrictions make it difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log is taking some time to appear in your log file because you are using

```
immediateFlush="false"
```

If you switch it to **true**, you will see the logs appearing immediately, but it might impact the performance of the application.

By default, **bufferedIO** is *true* and **bufferSize** is *8192 bytes*. This means that the logs will only be written to disk after the buffer has 8192 chars.

Refer to https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html for more details.